# Parametric or Subtype Polymorphism in Scala

Tags: scala, polymorphism

I want to clarify if I have rights defining these two cases of polymorphism:

### First:

```
class Operations

trait ExpAlg {
  type Opr <: Operations
  def lit(x: Int): Opr
}

trait Eval extends Operations {
  def eval(): Int
}
trait EvalExpAlg extends ExpAlg {
  type Opr = Eval
  def lit(x: Int) = new Eval() {
    def eval() = x
  }
}
```

Is it using Subtype polymorphism with Bounds and Traits?

### Second:

```
trait ExpAlg[E] {
  def lit(x: Int): E
}
trait Eval {
  def eval(): Int
}
trait EvalExpAlg extends ExpAlg[Eval] {
  def lit(x: Int) = new Eval() {
    def eval() = x
  }
}
```

Is it using Subtype polymorphism with Invariant type parameters and Traits? Or maybe it's  a mixing between parametric and subtype polymorphism?

I get these conclusions reading [this](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html) article.

Comment: is this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, abstract type and type parameter are sort of alternative to each other. You can find tons of materials on the subject, such as [this one](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=270195).

That being said, the only real difference between your examples is the fact that the first one uses bounded type and second one doesn't. However, in both cases EvalExpAlg extends ExpAlg and provides its implementation of lit(), which makes it a case of subtype polymorphism.

So, I would say that both examples are cases of using subtype polymorphism, not parametric (parametric would require the implementation to be identical for all types instead of provided separately by each subclass). The difference in the first one compared to second one is in the a) usage of upper bound and b) usage of abstract type instead of type parameter.

Comment: thanks a million. I reanalyzed again and again and I found somewhere something called "Parameterized inheritance" as a mixing of Subtype and Parametric polymorphism. Depending if I see from the Eval or Lit side it looks that I am using two techniques...

Comment: I just noticed that I had a huge typo - I said "... the only real difference between them is the fact that ..." and it appeared as if I was referring to the two polymorphisms. I meant the difference between *your examples*, not the two types of polymorphism. I fixed it now